# How to add a very large number of columns to a pre-existing table in H2?

Tags: sql, h2

I'm trying to test H2's performance on a table with anywhere from 2880 to 14,400 columns. I know it's very questionable design-wise, but I'd just like to run performance tests to measure the actual response time on such a gigantic table. An alternative I am looking at is to just add extra rows and store the extra information that way.

How would I go about generating thousands of new columns with different names. Because when you do a `ALTER TABLE table_name ADD column_name datatype;` statement, I don't believe `column_name` can actually be a concatenated string build through a loop, can it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE table_name ADD ('
    || (SELECT LISTAGG(' C' || X || ' INTEGER') FROM SYSTEM_RANGE(1, 1000))
    || ')';
```

Note: support for this command was introduced only in H2 1.4.200.

Please also note that H2, like many others, will read the complete row with in the most cases (only some queries can read all required values from an index). It means that there will be large overhead when you need only few columns.

Comment: If I wanted to use this script to instead insert thousands of rows, how could I go about that ? This is what I've got at the moment (not much). `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO component_schedule (component_schedule_id, component_id, component_schedule_start_time, component_schedule_end_time, component_available_then) VALUES ('
    || (SELECT LISTAGG(' C' || X || ' INTEGER') FROM SYSTEM_RANGE(1, 10))
    || ')';`